# When ploting 3d scalar field with Matlab, why axis X exchanges with Y?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

When I draw the isosurface of a 3d scalar field `A(i,j,k)` (i=1~31, j=1~151, k=1~151) using Matlab, in the figure, indice j corresponds to X axis, i corresponds to Y axis. How does Matlab arrange 3d data?

Here is the figure I drew:

[image: here is the figure I drew]

The cubic mesh is 31x151x151. But in the figure, the length in the X direction is 151, the length in the Y direction is 31. And the figure is the mirror image of the one I want.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? Along with additional details on the result you expect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Matlab docs for the `mesh` function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html), it appears that the Y axis uses the first index of the matrix and not the second. E.G. in a `(i,j)` index couple, `i` will be on axis Y and `j` will be on axis X. I've had quite an extended discussion about it with coworkers, and it appears to come down to the way Matlab stores its matrices internally: it stores a list of columns ([column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)), there a pretty interesting explaination here: http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f22019

TL;DR the first dimension is the columns (Y), then go the rows (X), then all further axes in order.